Using discord.py, how can I scrape all past messages sent on the server?
I am making a discord AI chatbot trained off messages sent in the server. I need to take all messages that have been sent in the general channel, put them in a list, and get their 'content' value. Here is what I have been trying:
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name="general")

    #print(channel.history())
    messages = [message async for message in channel.history()]
    print(messages)

when I run this code, It gives me a list with data from each message sent in the general channel. This data looks something like this when printed in the terminal:
<Message id=1254275339253846027 channel=<TextChannel id=1254271988826898462 name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=1254245331667783744> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=775486294435954689 name='nosics' global_name='Nosics' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=1254245331667783743 name="Nosics's server" shard_id=0 chunked=True member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>

There should be a 'content' variable listed in that data, but for some reason there is not. I can do things like
print(message.id)

and it works just fine. But for whatever reason, message.content doesnt exist, or is at least not given to me. Any ideas?

Don't put the answer into the question.  If you want your question to be useful to other people in the future, please take the time to post the answer properly.  (And maybe do the research to figure out why the code in the question didn't work.) Otherwise, my advice is to delete the question ... before it gets downvoted for doing it the wrong way!

Note: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que.  But if I did what is suggested there, you wouldn't get any reputation for upvotes on the answer!  (And this could be duplicate anyway.  I haven't checked ...)

Thanks Stephen! Sorry, I'm new to posting on the site. How could I share my answer more properly so that others who may be having a similar problem can find it?

I fixed my problem:
    @bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.text_channels, name="general")

    counter = 0
    async for message in channel.history(limit=999999):
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        print(message.content)


Were you not getting the content properly before and instead trying to get content from the whole list?
